# How to register classic printer to google cloud print

Tags: google-cloud-print

How to register classic printers (e.g. HP or Samsung printer) to google cloud print using service register API(https://www.google.com/cloudprint/interface/register) call. I am passing these required parameters-

```
'printer' => 'My classic printer',
'proxy'   => '212121',
'capabilities' => '<XPS capabilities data>',
'defaults' => '<XPS capabilities data>'
```

As I am not sure from where to get proxy id, I am passing arbitrary value. I am making the call using PHP CURL. Once the printer is registerd using API call it is showing printer type as 'Cloud ready printer' and connection status as 'unknown' in google account's printer list interface.

But if i do mannual register using google chrome browser it is showing as 'Classic printer connected via Google Chrome' and connection status as 'Online'.

Please comment if anyone has any idea..

Answer (score 2):

Printers show as 'Online' if the software that registered the printer maintains an active XMPP connection to Cloud Print. When you use Google Chrome to connect the printer, Chrome maintains an XMPP connection to Cloud Print. When you register the printer using the API directly, I'm guessing your PHP code also doesn't create an XMPP connection for that printer. You'll still be able to submit jobs to your 'Offline' printer, it's just that Cloud Print won't be able to send the printer a notification about the newly submitted print job. If you'd like to create an XMPP connection to Cloud Print, you can read more about it here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/devguide#receiving

Regarding the differences in label (Cloud Ready vs Classic Printer), Chrome adds some tags into the printer to help Cloud Print identify the printer as being connected through Chrome.